# Linux: Random kernel oops in mmap functions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, ubuntu-13.10

For the last month or so I've been getting seemingly random kernel oopses. I've started to notice a pattern: from looking at the traces, the call trace always involves mmap functions.

Whenever one of these happens, the process that it occurred under (Chromium in the trace below) hangs and trying to kill it with `SIGKILL` only results in the `kill` command hanging as well. To return stability to the system I have to completely power off the box and reboot.

Until a recent kernel update, the computer would just randomly turn off completely. No warnings and nothing in the logs. Thankfully, that has seemed to stop.

Question: Is this indicative of a hardware problem? Mmap failures suggest RAM problems (I ran memcheck for 12+ hours with no errors though). Or is this really just a bug in the kernel? If so, what can I do about it?

```
$ uname -a
Linux [name] 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Trace from `dmesg`:

```
[252563.113569] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000020000000018
[252563.113589] IP: [<ffffffff811619e0>] vma_interval_tree_insert+0x30/0x90
[252563.113607] PGD 0 
[252563.113612] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[252563.113620] Modules linked in: serpent_avx_x86_64 serpent_sse2_x86_64 serpent_generic twofish_generic twofish_avx_x86_64 twofish_x86_64_3way twofish_x86_64 twofish_common xts hidp pci_stub vboxpci(OF) vboxnetadp(OF) vboxnetflt(OF) vboxdrv(OF) vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci parport_pc ppdev rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc usblp x86_pkg_temp_thermal kvm_intel kvm eeepc_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel joydev snd_hda_codec btusb bluetooth cdc_acm snd_hwdep snd_pcm microcode snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer psmouse snd serio_raw mei_me mei lpc_ich soundcore mac_hid coretemp lp parport dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_memcpy async_raid6_recov async_pq async_xor async_tx xor hid_generic raid6_pq raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid raid1 mxm_wmi radeon crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit ttm ahci libahci drm_kms_helper e1000e drm video ptp pps_core wmi
[252563.113870] CPU: 3 PID: 13428 Comm: Chrome_IOThread Tainted: GF          O 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu
[252563.113890] Hardware name: ASUS All Series/MAXIMUS VI HERO, BIOS 0224 04/25/2013
[252563.113906] task: ffff88079bc9aee0 ti: ffff880768020000 task.ti: ffff880768020000
[252563.113922] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff811619e0>]  [<ffffffff811619e0>] vma_interval_tree_insert+0x30/0x90
[252563.113943] RSP: 0018:ffff880768021d90  EFLAGS: 00010206
[252563.113954] RAX: 0000020000000000 RBX: ffff8806d7f4c980 RCX: 0000000000000000
[252563.113969] RDX: ffff88079bb7bd70 RSI: ffff88079bb7bd70 RDI: ffff88038fa57c38
[252563.113984] RBP: ffff880768021d98 R08: 000000000000007f R09: 0000000000000000
[252563.114000] R10: ffff88038fa57c38 R11: 00007f3f14132000 R12: ffff88038fa57c38
[252563.114015] R13: ffff880100babae8 R14: ffff880100babaf0 R15: ffff88079bb7bd88
[252563.114030] FS:  00007f3f4fffe700(0000) GS:ffff88081ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[252563.114047] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[252563.114059] CR2: 0000020000000018 CR3: 00000007ed0b8000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
[252563.114074] Stack:
[252563.114079]  ffffffff8116b698 ffff880768021dd8 ffffffff8116c275 ffff880100babac8
[252563.114097]  ffff880100babaf0 00007f3f140b2000 ffff880100babae8 ffff8806daf9fd00
[252563.114114]  ffff880100babac8 ffff880768021e60 ffffffff8116e77c ffff8806daf9fd00
[252563.114132] Call Trace:
[252563.114139]  [<ffffffff8116b698>] ? __vma_link_file+0x48/0x80
[252563.114153]  [<ffffffff8116c275>] vma_link+0x75/0xc0
[252563.114164]  [<ffffffff8116e77c>] mmap_region+0x48c/0x610
[252563.114177]  [<ffffffff8116ec05>] do_mmap_pgoff+0x305/0x3c0
[252563.114190]  [<ffffffff8115a3fd>] vm_mmap_pgoff+0x8d/0xc0
[252563.114202]  [<ffffffff8116d253>] SyS_mmap_pgoff+0x1d3/0x270
[252563.114215]  [<ffffffff81017402>] SyS_mmap+0x22/0x30
[252563.114227]  [<ffffffff816f721d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[252563.114240] Code: 48 8b 47 08 48 2b 07 49 89 fa 4c 8b 8f 98 00 00 00 48 89 f2 31 c9 48 c1 e8 0c 4d 8d 44 01 ff eb 27 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <4c> 39 40 18 73 04 4c 89 40 18 4c 3b 48 40 48 8d 48 08 48 8d 50 
[252563.114312] RIP  [<ffffffff811619e0>] vma_interval_tree_insert+0x30/0x90
[252563.114327]  RSP <ffff880768021d90>
[252563.114335] CR2: 0000020000000018
[252563.117845] ---[ end trace eb82b12e51fc5733 ]---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have run *memtest* for a sufficient amount of time, the most obvious hardware suspect has been disculpated. I take it that you have noticed whether the line

```
 BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000020000000018
```

carries the same or a different address every time, right?

I cannot help you with this report, but may I suggest you use *Apport* for collecting info on your crashes? *Apport* is Ubuntu's official package for data collection in cases of crashes and bugs, you find a [good Intro here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).

You need to activate it, (edit as sudo /etc/apport/crashdb.conf, find this line,

```
  'problem_types': ['Bug', 'Package'],
```

and add a hash symbol, <kbd>#</kbd> at its beginning), and it will produce a full trace of the call that generated the crash. No need to worry about *ulimit* either in  recent versions of Ubuntu, since *Apport* is able to circumvent its indication, even if set to 0.

By and large, the best thing to do is to upload the crash report to Launchpad; Apport does this automatically. Yet there is some info that may be helpful even to the unexperienced user. The Intro referenced above states:

```
Some fields warrant further details:

SegvAnalysis: when examining a Segmentation Fault (signal 11), Apport attempts to review the exact machine instruction that caused the fault, and checks the program counter, source, and destination addresses, looking for any virtual memory address (VMA) that is outside an allocated range (as reported in the ProcMaps attachment).

SegvReason: a VMA can be read from, written to, or executed. On a SegFault, one of these 3 CPU actions has taken place at a given VMA that either not allocated, or lacks permissions to perform the action. For example:

SegvReason: reading NULL VMA would mean that a NULL pointer was most likely dereferenced while reading a value.

SegvReason: writing unknown VMA would mean that something was attempting to write to the destination of a pointer aimed outside of allocated memory. (This is sometimes a security issue.)

SegvReason: executing writable VMA [stack] would mean that something was causing code on the stack to be executed, but the stack (correctly) lacked execute permissions. (This is almost always a security issue.)
```

In the past, this has allowed me to pinpoint a program with a bug (VirtualBox) which caused the crashes. After a full purge and re-install, the problem evaporated. I just wish you the same luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The paging request address is indeed at a different address each time. I guess I'll just have to report the problem next time it happens and hope for a fix in the future.